# Submitting a Storm topology fails /getting started)

Tags: java, apache-storm

I'm trying to get started with Storm. I setup a hosted cluster. I followed all the steps listed [here](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter) for getting started. It works fine till submitting:

`storm jar target/storm-starter-*.jar org.apache.storm.starter.RollingTopWords production-topology` fails with

```
Running: java -client -Ddaemon.name= -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/usr/local/Cellar/storm/1.2.2/libexec -Dstorm.log.dir=/usr/local/Cellar/storm/1.2.2/libexec/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /usr/local/Cellar/storm/1.2.2/libexec/*:/usr/local/Cellar/storm/1.2.2/libexec/lib/*:/usr/local/Cellar/storm/1.2.2/libexec/extlib/*:target/storm-starter-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/storm/1.2.2/libexec/conf:/usr/local/Cellar/storm/1.2.2/libexec/bin -Dstorm.jar=target/storm-starter-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dstorm.dependency.jars= -Dstorm.dependency.artifacts={} org.apache.storm.starter.RollingTopWords production-topology
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.storm.starter.RollingTopWords
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/storm/topology/ConfigurableTopology
```

I'm not familiar with Java and Storm but getting started doesn't feel any good yet.

Answer (score 1):

ConfigurableTopology doesn't exist in Storm 1.2.2. Most likely you are trying to use a storm-starter jar built from Storm 2.x with a 1.2.2 cluster. This will not work. Build storm-starter from the 1.x sources instead, and it should work.